# Error after installing provider package ^3.1.0 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I had installed provider package 3.1.0 and had this error while running.

/C:/Users/Praveen/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/Praveen/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
  ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/Praveen/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
  : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of provider:

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^6.0.0
```